# Log4J NTEventLogAppender DLL not found

Tags: java, dll, log4j, event-log

Hy ppl,

I'm having a problem trying to use Log4J's NTEventLogAppender.

I've set my Log4J properties like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CA, NTEventLog 


    #Console Appender 
    log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender 
    log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
    log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n 

    #File Appender 
    log4j.appender.FA=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender 
    log4j.appender.FA.File=sample.log 
    log4j.appender.FA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
    log4j.appender.FA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

    #Event Log Appender
    log4j.appender.NTEventLog=org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender
    log4j.appender.NTEventLog.source=ESB Web Services


    # Set the logger level of File Appender to WARN 
    log4j.appender.FA.Threshold = WARN
```

Following the advice [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/nt/NTEventLogAppender.html), I've placed NTEventLogAppender.amd64.dll file on my System32 Folder, but when I try to instance a class that uses a Logger I get this exception:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: NTEventLogAppender (Not found in java.library.path)**

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is to allow you to debug easily*:

If you did add the dll in the System32 folder, make sure that the directory is also included in Java's library path `java.library.path`:

To test (via code):

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
```

Output (partial):

> C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;**C:\Windows\system32**;C:\Windows;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program
>   Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\80\Tools\BINN;C:\Program
>   Files\RemObjects
>   Software\Everwood\Bin;C:\Program
>   Files\RemObjects Software\RemObjects
>   SDK for Delphi\Dcu\D7;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\80\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program
>   Files\Embarcadero\Delphi
>   Prism\bin;C:\Program Files\Developer
>   Express.VCL\Library\Delphi14;C:\Program
>   Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program
>   Files\Developer
>   Express.VCL\Library\Delphi7

Comment: Thanks

I've checked the path and C:\Windows\system32 is on it

Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Despite having the System32 on my java build path, I've placed it on:

C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WID7_WTE\runtimes\bi_v7\java\jre\bin

That also was on my build path and finally got it working

Thanks!